# Floating div from left to right to top and bottom where left div sit bottom and right div top

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 divs next to each other and on ipad(portrait) i want the right div to display on top of left div.

**Code:**

```
 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.both {
   width: 100%;
   display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.left-go-bottom, right-go-top {
   height: 769px;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: darkblue;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 769px;
}
```

The first div class **.left-go-bottom** is first and wil be on the left the second div class **right-go-top** is second and wil float on right side.

For my media query at the break point i added.

**Css:**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and 
  (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

.left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 }

}
```

So it works fine, but the div on the top i need on the bottom and the one currently bottom i need top, i tried floating the top one right and bottom left , did not work, any help please.

Comment: see `flexbox` positioning along with the `order` property: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thanks wil check into that @fcalderan

Comment: added an answer below. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display:flex;` on `.both` and then in the `media query` use `flex-direction:column-reverse` this will reverse the order of your boxes

i have added `background:red` to the `right-go-top` div for example purposes.
also changed the `media query` for the same reason ( it will work the same with your `media query` )

see **snippet** below or jsfiddle > **[jsfiddle flex](https://jsfiddle.net/zm4ga2xL/1/)**

let me know if it helps

```css
.both {
   width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.left-go-bottom,.right-go-top  {
   height: 769px;
   width:50%;
}
 .left-go-bottom{
   background-color: darkblue;  
}
 .right-go-top{
   background-color: red;  
}

 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 }
 .both {
   flex-direction:column-reverse
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="both">

   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT with new code from OP

**OPTION 1 :** delete the `height` from `.main` . because you have set a fixed height of 769px on the `main`s content ( right and left div ) so `.main` will inherit the height from the content .

so it will have an automatic height of 769px when right and left div are on the same line , and will have a height of 769px*2 = 1538 on mobile version . this happens automatically if you don't write a fixed height.

see snippet below with this solution

```css
.both {
   width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* height:758px removed */ 
}
.left-go-bottom,.right-go-top  {
   height: 769px;
   width:50%;
}
 .left-go-bottom{
   background-color: darkblue;  
}
 .left-go-bottom.green {
   background:green
 }
 .right-go-top{
   background-color: red;  
}
  .right-go-top.yellow{
   background-color: yellow;  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 }
 .both {
   flex-direction:column-reverse;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom green"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top yellow"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom green"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top yellow"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Option B** not recommended . but you can set a fixed height on `.main` , although it's useless because, as i said in the previous solution, `.main` inherits its height from the two divs that are inside it and that have fixed height of 769px

but if you really want to. you can set height 769px on desktop version, and 1538px when the divs go on different lines. ( their height combined )

see snippet below :

```css
.both {
   width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 769px;
}
.left-go-bottom,.right-go-top  {
   height: 769px;
   width:50%;
}
 .left-go-bottom{
   background-color: darkblue;  
}
 .left-go-bottom.green {
   background:green
 }
 .right-go-top{
   background-color: red;  
}
  .right-go-top.yellow{
   background-color: yellow;  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 }
 .both {
   flex-direction:column-reverse;
 }
 .main {
     height: 1538px; /* added */
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom green"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top yellow"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
 <div class="both">
   <div class="left-go-bottom green"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top yellow"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Best answer and way of using Flexbox here, but to show OP the flexibility of Flexbox, it's also possible to keep `flex-direction: row` (default) and set `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` on flex container. Each will occupy 1 line _starting from bottom_ https://jsfiddle.net/zm4ga2xL/4/ . Pre-flexbox way of doing it was a nasty hack with `display: table-caption` https://jsfiddle.net/zm4ga2xL/5/

Comment: This worked for me doing the flex direction:column reverse but overlaps with other divs around it, any info on how to make sure that does not happen? Thanks @MihaiT im looking deep into your code making it work, feels like i am almost there.

Comment: well can you share a little bit more of your code ? so i can see where the problem is ?

Comment: Please have a look at the question i first asked, i did make an edit showing that i have more than one of the same main block. @MihaiT thanks

Comment: overlapping other content it's because you set `   height: 769px;` on `.main` . just remove it because main will have a height on mobile of `2*769px=1538px` because your 2 divs with height 769px are one after the other. so that's why only one div fits inside the main and you think it's overlaping. either you remove the height completely from `main` ( because it inherits the height of it's content ) or you set height:1538px in media query ( i will edit answer aswell )

Comment: awesome answer i did not even think about it in that way how the fixed height has an impact  on the mobile device, rookie mistake, asif im not. Thanks again you did resolve my question, HELPED allot! @MihaiT

Answer (score 0):

If they don't contain content that can't be doubled, the simplest solution is to create a copy of the right block and hiding or showing it accordingly.

```
<div class="both">
    <div class="right-go-top show-only-on-iPad-portrait"></div>
    <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
    <div class="right-go-top hide-on-iPad-portrait"></div>
</div>


<style>
.show-only-on-iPad-portrait {
    display:none;
}
.hide-on-iPad-portrait {
    display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and 
  (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

.show-only-on-iPad-portrait {
    display:block;
}
.hide-on-iPad-portrait {
    display:none;
}

}
</style>
```

Comment: They definitely have content, did not think it would be necessary to add it, ok your idea will work in a way its not really what i am looking for, css code would be nice. For mobile i choose to resolve such issue with displaying none and adding new div for mobile only , but their should be css for ipad to get this working, i hope.

Comment: Try this: @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and 
  (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

.left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 }

}

Comment: Sorry, I am on a mobile.. Don't look at the comment

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly because it uses absolute position and this is not responsive, but this does the staff

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and 
  (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  .left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      display: block;
  }

  .left-go-bottom{
      top: 769px;
      position: absolute;
  }

  .right-go-top{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @conversetjordan this is a solution but i do not want to use position absolute, i have divs outside this main div, and it will definitely have an impact on them using absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MihaiT for the help my problem resolved.

This is my answer that works.

**code:**

```
 <div class="main">
  <div class="both">
    <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
    <div class="right-go-top"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
  <div class="both unique-flex">
   <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
   <div class="right-go-top"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="main">
  <div class="both">
    <div class="left-go-bottom"></div>
    <div class="right-go-top"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**css:**

```
.main{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 769px;
}

.both {
   width: 100%;
   display:-webkit-inline-box;
}

.left-go-bottom,.right-go-top  {
    height: 769px;
    width:50%;
 }


 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and
 (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  .left-go-bottom, .right-go-top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }

  .both {
    display:block;
  }

  .main {
    float: left;
    display: inline-table;
   }

  div.both.unique-flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
 }
```

As you can see i made the blocks i want to switch unique to them self and the one on top and bottom used display:block.